# Autocompletetextview не могу получить текст во время ввода

Tags: android

У меня есть `autocompletetextview` на него, я повесил слушатель `addTextChangedListener`, а в него непосредственно передал `TextWatcher`. Проблема следующая мне нужно получить символ сразу после ввода. То есть, человек ввел букву, мне нужно ее считать и отправить на север вот пример моего кода. Не понимаю по чем не отрабатывает.

```
 private void initActCity() {
    adapterActCity = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, cityNameList);
    actCity.setAdapter(adapterActCity );
    actCity.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            actCity.showDropDown();
            actCity.requestFocus();
            return false;
        }
    });
    actCity.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }@Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (s.length()>0) {
                int a = actCity.getText().length();
                if (a == 0) {
                    cityNameList.clear();
               } else if (a == 1) {
                    // Сдесь если есть символ то получить его и отправить.
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });
```

Также пробовал добавить простой `TextView` и передавать в него значение из метода `onTextChanged` следующим образом `textview.setText(actCity.getText);` -- ни к чем не привело `textView` пустое, я понимаю что где-то не срабатывает, пробовал пройти под дебагом, не могу это место пройти оно его прокидывает. Помогите пожалуйста!

Answer (score 3):

Надо проверять на длину не это

```
int a = actCity.getText().length();
```

а вот это

```
CharSequence s
```

Символ в onTextChanged появляется раньше чем в самом поле ввода, поэтому actCity.getText() пустой в этот момент

Answer (score -1):

Перенеси код из `onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)` в `afterTextChanged(Editable s)`. Введенные символы получишь так:

```
final String stroka = s.toString();
```

где s это Editable